# Marionette JS : Properly clear ItemView when listening other model events

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, destructor, destroy

When an **ItemView** is listening to a model other than its model (this.model), do I simply need to turn off listeners within the **remove** function? And set their reference to null? I wonder if the **ItemView** will be safely destroyed, or if I'll be in trouble later when tons of views like this will be created / destroyed?

Example :

```
var FriendListItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    [...]
    initialize: function(){
        Marionette.ItemView.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
        // get the friend and the user from global "users" collection
        this.user = users.get(this.model.get('user_id'));
        this.friend = users.get(this.model.get('friend_id'));
        this.user.on('change:name', this.render, this);
        this.friend.on('change:name', this.render, this);
    },
    remove: function(){
        this.user.off('change:name', this.render, this);
        this.friend.off('change:name', this.render, this);
        this.user = null;
        this.friend = null;
        Marionette.ItemView.prototype.remove.apply(this, arguments);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `this.user.on('change:name', this.render, this);` use the [listenTo()](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) function.

```
this.listenTo(this.user, 'change:name', this.render);
```

Marionette will in its default [destroy](http://marionettejs.com/annotated-src/backbone.marionette.html#section-231) call the [remove](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) method from Backbone, which again will call `stopListening` and clear out all event listeners registered via `listenTo`. That should make your entire remove-function unnessescary. These kind of things is one of the problems that Marionette is meant to take care of for you. Setting `this.user` and `this.friends` to null is also unnessescary.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Nice, complete and clear answer thanks ivarni!

Comment: From my own tests using the Marionette explorer, if you do not manually call this.model.destroy(); in onDestroy(), the model is never destroyed.

Comment: @Growiel I'd love to see a demo of that behaviour since I just linked to the sourcecode which clearly calls those methods. Is this perhaps an older version?

Answer (score 1):

just to clarify a bit further.  The destroy method will also trigger events and call related methods.  Additionally ItemView's initialize is a noop, so no reason to call the prototype.  Most everything has before and after event hooks so you don't need to call the prototype.

```
var FriendListItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  [...]
  initialize: function(){
    // get the friend and the user from global "users" collection
    this.user = users.get(this.model.get('user_id'));
    this.friend = users.get(this.model.get('friend_id'));        
    this.listenTo(this.user, 'change:name' this.render);
    this.listenTo(this.friend, 'change:name' this.render);
  },
  onDestroy: function(){
    // you could do additional clean up here if you needed to
    // but you don't.  There's also an onBeforeDestroy
    // equivalent to this.on('destroy', this.doSomething);
  },
});
```